# Configure application extension mapping via command line or script

Tags: configuration, iis-6, windows-server-2003

Is there any way to add an IIS 6 application extension mapping via the command line?  And in particular I'd like to automate the configuration of the wildcard application map such that the **Verify that file exists** option is unchecked.  Is there any way to set that via a script or command?